# Typescript JSON data without key

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am trying to access `IssueId` from the json data below:

```
[
 {
  "-MERcLq7nCj5c5gwpYih":
     {"CreateDate":"2020-08-11T08:27:13.300Z","Id":"-MERcLq7nCj5c5gwpYih","IssueId":"-ME3-tuhyqlaRdZCRapj","StatusId":"2", ...},
  "-MERdViSr8oCUGsCHouS":
     {"CreateDate":"2020-08-11T08:32:15.901Z","Id":"-MERdViSr8oCUGsCHouS","IssueId":"-ME3-tuhyqlaRdZCRapj","StatusId":"3", ...},
 ...
 },
 ...
]
```

I need to get the latest status ID parse to an object but to do that I must get the CreateDate, My problem is I can't select each item because there is no key.
I encountered a few JSON Typescript examples here, but nothing like this. Can someone explain to me if there is a way to get the content without going through this value `-MERcLq7nCj5c5gwpYih`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **for...in statement** for looping over object try below example

```
export class AppComponent  {
  data = [
  {
    "-MERcLq7nCj5c5gwpYih": {
      "CreateDate": "2020-08-11T08:27:13.300Z",
      "Id": "-MERcLq7nCj5c5gwpYih",
      "IssueId": "-ME3-tuhyqlaRdZCRapj",
      "StatusId": "2"
    },
    "-MERdViSr8oCUGsCHouS":
    {
      "CreateDate": "2020-08-11T08:32:15.901Z",
      "Id": "-MERdViSr8oCUGsCHouS",
      "IssueId": "-ME3-tuhyqlaRdZCRapj",
      "StatusId": "3"
    }
  }
]

  ngOnInit(){
    const obj = this.data[0] // I am assuming you have one object inside array
    for (const property in obj) {
        console.log(obj[property].CreateDate)
        console.log(obj[property].StatusId)
    }
  }
}
```

Documentation for for..in
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Thank you very much this just saved me a lot of reading time, I'm marking this is the correct solution since I prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` to get the keys of the object and iterate over them to get the property that you want like below:

```js
const obj = [{
  "-MERcLq7nCj5c5gwpYih": {
    "CreateDate": "2020-08-11T08:27:13.300Z",
    "Id": "-MERcLq7nCj5c5gwpYih",
    "IssueId": "-ME3-tuhyqlaRdZCRapj",
    "StatusId": "2",

  },
  "-MERdViSr8oCUGsCHouS": {
    "CreateDate": "2020-08-11T08:32:15.901Z",
    "Id": "-MERdViSr8oCUGsCHouS",
    "IssueId": "-ME3-tuhyqlaRdZCRapj",
    "StatusId": "3",

  }
}]

const target = obj[0]
const keys = Object.keys(target);
console.log(keys) 
//[
//  "-MERcLq7nCj5c5gwpYih",
//  "-MERdViSr8oCUGsCHouS"
//]

keys.forEach(k=> console.log(target[k].IssueId)) // access by key sample
// -ME3-tuhyqlaRdZCRapj
// -ME3-tuhyqlaRdZCRapj
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution I just tested it and works like charm ):.

Answer (score 0):

For nested objects, for example:

```
var nestedObjects={
  "-MERcLq7nCj5c5gwpYih":
     {"CreateDate":"2020-08-11T08:27:13.300Z","Id":"-MERcLq7nCj5c5gwpYih","IssueId":"-ME3-tuhyqlaRdZCRapj","StatusId":"2", ...},
  "-MERdViSr8oCUGsCHouS":
     {"CreateDate":"2020-08-11T08:32:15.901Z","Id":"-MERdViSr8oCUGsCHouS","IssueId":"-ME3-tuhyqlaRdZCRapj","StatusId":"3", ...},
 ...
 }
```

You can do something like this for nested objects:

```
Object.keys(nestedObjects).forEach(key => {
   var objectThatYouWantToAccessWithoutKnowingKeyBeforeHand=nestedObjects[key];

   // Then you can access your object:
   console.log(objectThatYouWantToAccessWithoutKnowingKeyBeforeHand.CreateDate);
   console.log(objectThatYouWantToAccessWithoutKnowingKeyBeforeHand.Id);
})
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is the same as @Eldar below, I was actually unaware that Object.Keys exists.